# Was Frankenstein's Monster really an illusion?

Tags: frankenstein, mary-shelley

I am investigating about Gothic Literature, more concretely about Mary Shelley's *Frankenstein*, and realized there was **a theory on the possibility of Frankenstein's monster being an illusion** ([some info can be found available here](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1385522-did-the-creature-even-exist)).

*Is there any paper or specific publication mentioning this theory?*

Answer (score 5):

The first relevant document I managed to discover on this is an undergraduate biology thesis titled *[The Real "Monster" in Frankenstein](https://augusta.openrepository.com/bitstream/handle/10675.2/620919/Urizar_D_2016.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y)*. Here is an extract from the abstract:

> I argue that that the real “monster” of the story is in fact Victor
>   Frankenstein who is suffering from paranoid schizophrenia and that the “monster” is really just
>   a delusions that Victor uses to cope with the idea that he in fact is the killer of the story.

I wasn't sure if an undergraduate level paper was sufficient to answer the question but, fortunately, the author included two supportive references from more mainstream journals.

First is *[Probing the Psychological Mystery of Frankenstein](https://scholarcommons.sc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1297&context=engl_facpub)* from *Approaches to Teaching Shelley's Frankenstein*. This goes into detail as to how a teacher can guide a class into considering that the monster may be a manifestation of Frankenstein's schizophrenia. For example:

> I call attention to the many times throughout the
>   novel that Victor falls asleep or loses consciousness and how he explicitly acknowledges his own culpability when he first sees the corpse of each of the "monster's" victims.
>
> I point out a passage in which the Creature reminds Frankenstein of their physical kinship ("my form is a filthy type of yours, more horrid even from the very resemblance"
>
> I call attention to the similarity of many of their utterances. For example, each in his own way cries to a mocking universe, "if ye really pity me, crush sensation and memory", just as each describes himself repeatedly as a "miserable wretch." Each, motivated by blind revenge, destroys himself as he seeks the annihilation of the other. One is the slave of the
>   other and at the same time master and executioner.

Second is *[The Myth of the Monster in Mary's Shelley's Murder Mystery](https://www.pval.org/cms/lib/NY19000481/Centricity/Domain/105/Frankenstein%20Critique.pdf)* from *Journal of South Texas English Studies*. This makes a similar argument more from a close reading of the text than a medical examination. For example:

> Another interesting comment that throws into doubt the existence of this being is when
>   Frankenstein says, “Clerval, my friend and dearest companion, had fallen a victim to me and
>   the monster of my creation”. The monster of his creation can be seen as a metaphor for
>   his delusions rather than an actual creature.
>
> The ambiguity in Shelley’s novel makes a single, definitive reading impossible. It is not clear
>   from the text whether a creature exists who stalks his creator, killing all of the people close
>   to him, or whether Frankenstein is actually a deranged killer with an alter ego who goes on a
>   killing spree. Either reading is just as plausible.

Of course, both these papers include their own references which may also be of help for further reading.